# How to print iptable firewall rules?

Tags: firewall, iptables

How does one print or dump the firewall rules being used by `iptables` in an effort to trouble shoot connection problems?

I'm fairly certain its going to include `-L` or `--list`, but I'm not sure of other options that will be helpful in troubleshooting a connection problem because I rarely use iptables directly from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Are you taking about exporting them to a txt file?

If so, that would be `iptables --list > /path/to/txt/file_name.txt`

Comment: Will the command list most (all?) the information necessary to diagnose a typical connection problem? (Is 'typical' a bad word here?) For example, do I need another switch in addition to `--list` to list other useful information? Will it keep extra noise to a minimum, or do I need another switch to remove extraneous information that pollutes output and confuses interpretation for someone not familiar with the output?

Comment: well, typical is a bit vague, which should be avoided here. Be specific. But yes, i understand what you mean by typical. Unless you are doing more in depth firewall rules like NATTING, `--list` should be fine. But you can specify which chain you can display.

Comment: `iptables -L INPUT` specifies a chain to show. This one shows the INPUT chain

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of printing out an iptables rule set. You're right to include `-L`, but for troubleshooting this is not always sufficient. To have a full listing, use the `-n` and `-v` options with the `-L`:

```
iptables -n -v -L
iptables -t yourtablename -n -v -L
```

that you can send to a txt file.

The `-v` (verbose) option may be very useful in troubleshooting, as it shows the packets/byte counters for each rule. With it, one can often find a rule which doesn't catch anything. The `-v` option shows also the interfaces (in and out), which are not shown with a simple `-L`.

The `-n` option makes it faster as it will not try to resolve ips to hosts.
If no `-t`, then table filter is default.

There is also the command `iptables-save -c` that show the rules the same way as they are entered on the command line (which is used for saving a rule set, that can be understood by iptables-restore to reload the rule set)